# How can I mount a speaker on to a Pi so that it is light enough for it to be mobile

Tags: audio, power

Can I mount a speaker on a mobile Pi robot together with a suitable power supply? Ideally I’d like the Pi to follow a fixed route while emitting a fixed repeating tone.

Comment: what does this mean? `light enough`

Comment: yes, you can use an USB sound stick and a speaker as small as half the size of the sound stick. Or you can consider a mini BlueTooth speaker.

Comment: A USB solution is possible, but not Bluetooth since I need the location of the sound source to move

Comment: Here is one solution I found. Does this fit your requirements.
[link]https://core-electronics.com.au/mini-external-usb-stereo-speaker.html[link]